# Uploading and displaying an image in Django

Tags: django, python-3.x

I am currently learning Django. I am building a system that gets input from the user as image and throws back the damage level. I have the python files all caught up. But I am having difficulty doing the Django part.

How do I get an image as input from the user ?

And how will I throw back the result of the code that does the damage level prediction to the front end ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: By using a file upload: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/http/file-uploads/

Comment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/http/file-uploads/, specifically the section "Handling uploaded files with a model"

Answer (score 0):

To get images from user you can do as following. However getting data from request is not recommended way.

**Views.py**

```
from django.shortcuts import render, render_to_response
from django.core.files.storage import FileSystemStorage


def index(request):
    if request.POST:

        if request.method == 'POST' and request.FILES['image']:
            uploaded_image = request.FILES['image']
            fs = FileSystemStorage()
            filename = fs.save(uploaded_image.name, uploaded_image)
            uploaded_file_url = fs.url(filename)
            code = get_code(uploaded_file_url)
            return render_to_response("homepage.html", {"code": code})

    else:
        return render(request, "homepage.html")
```

Using this `request.FILES['image']` we are getting a image from our form passed on post event.

In your template **homepage.html**

```
<form method="post" action="{% url 'code' %}" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            {% csrf_token %}
            <input type="file" name="image" id="file-input" accept="image/x-png,image/jpeg,image/jpg"/>


            <input type="submit" style="background: #0b0b0b" class="btn btn-secondary" value="Generate Caption"/>
            <br><br>
            <div style="background: #0b0b0b">
                <a>Code for image is : {{ code }}</a>
            </div>
        </form>
```

`{% url 'code' %}` this will reverse the url by name as defined in urls.py. `{% csrf_token %}` is required for security reasons. `enctype="multipart/form-data"` is required to pass data like images, files etc. Input with name `name="image"` is what we are looking in `request.FILES['image']`. If you want change the name make your to change it everywhere.

And in your **urls.py**

```
from django.conf.urls import url
urlpatterns = [
   url(r'^$', views.homepage, name='code'),  
]
```

Also you can have look at Django [forms](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/forms/) for a better way.